# UWP Bindings not initialized after InitializeComponent

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

DataBindings are not loaded in UWP after calling InitializeComponent. Because of this I am getting errors in my application trying manipulate things, which usually are bound to, but on Navigation bindings are not loaded. What is proper way of manipulating bound properties in OnNavigated events?

```
<Page
x:Class="StackApp.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:local="using:StackApp"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
mc:Ignorable="d">
<Grid>
    <ComboBox x:Name="cb" ItemsSource="{x:Bind Data}" />
</Grid></Page>
```

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    Data Data { get; set; } = Whatever;
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        //this.Bindings.Initialize();
        //it can solve problem by manual binding loading
    }
}

protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    cb.SelectedIndex = 0; // Crash, because ComboBox has no items loaded yet
}
```

Comment: Problem can be kind of solved by calling `Bindings.Initialize();` in constructor, but I want to know what is the root cause.

Comment: Add some code please, without it it is very hard to help, as we don't know any context of the issue

Comment: @MartinZikmund Added example problem

Comment: @Shadow: Wait until the `ComboBox` has been loaded? `cb.Loaded += (ss,ee) => cb.SelectedIndex = 0;`

Comment: @mm8 But I would like to know right way to do so. I feel that Your suggestion is workaround around bad design in the app.

Comment: @Shadow: It is bad design to assume that the bindings have been resolved in `OnNavigatedTo`. Aparently they haven't so you should wait until they have. That's why I suggested handling the `Loaded` event.

Comment: @mm8 Yes, but I would like to know more about Page lifecycle and so on. Also I think that in given example it would be better to bind `cb.SelectedIndex`, but it would not solve every corner case.

Comment: @Shadow: You should read the remarks section in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.page.onnavigatedto).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bindings have not yet been resolved in `OnNavigatedTo`. From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.page.onnavigatedto):

> Unlike in prior XAML platforms, the OnNavigated method is called before the visual tree is loaded. This has the following implications:
>
> - You cannot access a valid `Parent` property value from an override of `OnNavigated`. If you need to access the `Parent` property, do so in a `Loaded` event handler.
> - You cannot use `OnNavigatedTo` for element manipulation or state change of controls on the destination page. Instead, attach a `Loaded` event handler at the root of the newly loaded page's content, and perform any element manipulations, state changes, event wiring and so on in the `Loaded` event handler.

So to wait until the `ComboBox` has been loaded, you should handle the `Loaded` event:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    Data Data { get; set; } = Whatever;
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.Loaded += MainPage_Loaded;
    }

    private void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        cb.SelectedIndex = 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting errors from Output ?
Where is your data class located ?
Is the Datacontext set up ?

For example, if your xaml look like this :

```
<Page
x:Class="StackApp.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:local="using:StackApp"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
mc:Ignorable="d">
<Grid>
    <Button Content="{Binding}" />
</Grid></Page>
```

Then in your code behind you should set the DataContext like this :

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    String Test { get; set; } = "John";
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = Test;
    }
}
```

Comment: My problem is not related to the DataContext. I've added example code to question.

Comment: Use Loaded += MainPage_Loaded; before InitializeComponent then ?

Comment: Actually InitializeComponent execute on the UI Thread, so OnNavigated is called before the call back on your code behind's thread, that's why your app is crashing

Comment: I don't know exactly but the problem stay the same,
Constructor is called, launching the InitializeComponent on the UI Thread
Then OnNavigated is called just after the Constructor ends, then when InitializeComponent is done, Loaded is called.